# Disable wifi on router irregularly

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security

I want to disable wifi when I’m not at home (no regular pattern) and I’m searching for a good method to do that. Disabling would be doable with my phone over ssh, but the problem is how I would turn it on back again, because obviously my phone needs to be connected to the router. Even though I have a laptop, it is not always connected via ethernet and I’m looking for a rather convenient way.

Some ideas would be:

- Connect via VPN to the router to turn wifi back on
- Some hardware switch connected to a Raspberry Pie
- A router, that has such a switch?

Comment: *"A router, that has such a switch?"* -- I did look for this feature a few years ago, and it was a rare feature.  It was like just one or two wireless routers out two dozen had a dedicated button/switch to disable the radio.  IIRC DD-WRT can re-purpose a button (e.g. the WPS button) on some versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to turn off only the WiFi (you have something on the wired network that needs the router up all the time, even when you are not home) get an access point, and shut down the WiFi on your router (permanently) or get a different router without any WiFi (such as pfSense on a no-wifi box) and plug the Access Point into a power strip with a switch.

Otherwise, just plug the router you have into a power strip with a switch, which would be perfectly fine for most home installations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution is too much freaky but here it goes. You could have an Arduino (integrated with or without a Raspberry Pi, that depends on the implementation) that would use a [PIR motion sensor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/189), and which would also be connected by a RJ-45 cable to your router so if it detects the motion, it would connect to the router by a CLI (that, of course, assuming your router has a CLI - some admit SSH or Telnet connections to interact with them) and enable WiFi back again.

Also, you could use the same sensor to set up a timeout so if no move is detected for a while, it would disable WiFi automatically. The inconvenience I see there is that you would need to place the PIR sensor in a place where you mostly are when you're home, which might not be an easy task.

Maybe overkill but still a solution (if you like to play, overall).

[Here](https://diyhacking.com/arduino-motion-sensor-tutorial/) is a motion sensor tutorial if you're interested.